# Assignment of @GeneratedValue to otherthan ID column

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a model like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="QUESTIONNAIRE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "RA_QA_SEQ", sequenceName = "RA_QUESTIONNAIRE_SEQ")
public class Questionnaire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "RA_QA_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "QUESTID")
    private long questionID;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION")
    private String question;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "RA_QA_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "QUESTORDER")
    private long questionOrder;

    @Column(name = "QUESTCATEGORYID")
    private long questionCatgoryID;

        ....... list of setters and getters.......
}
```

Here I want the "questionID" value to be inserted for the "questionOrder" column also in DB. I thought to give the @GeneratedValue(generator = "RA_QA_SEQ") to "questionOrder" but still i am getting 0 for "questionOrder" in DB but "questionID" getting proper sequence value.

Please suggest me how I will get the value of "questionID" to "questionOrder" also.

Answer (score 0):

From the JPA 2.0 specification:

**11.1.17 GeneratedValue Annotation**

> The GeneratedValue annotation provides for the specification of
>   generation strategies for the values of primary keys. The
>   GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or
>   field of an entity or mapped superclass **in conjunction with the Id
>   annotation**.
>
> Portable applications **should not** use the GeneratedValue annotation on
>   other persistent fields or properties.

If you want just the questionOrder to hold the same value I think you could do:

```
// 2 fields are mapped to the same column, so one of these needs to be read-only
@Column(name = "QUESTID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private long questionOrder;
```

HTH.

Comment: with the above approach null value is getting inserted for questionOrder in the table instead of questid. Whether do i need to make insertable =true?

Comment: You mean that the `questionId` attribute (column = `QUESTID`) is also null? These two properties refers to the same column, so does it mean that the `questionOrder` overrode your generated ID?

Comment: questionId is getting value from sequence properly and inserting into DB properly but after making the change "@Column(name = "QUESTID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private long questionOrder;"  questionOrder is getting (null) and inserting (null) into DB table instead the same value of questionID

Comment: What is the column name of the null value?

Comment: column name questionOrder. i have replaced the @GeneratedValue(generator = "RA_QA_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "QUESTORDER")
    private long questionOrder;
 by @Column(name = "QUESTID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private long questionOrder; as you suggested. but I dont know how the questionOrder will get the same value as questionID?

Comment: @Chandu maybe we could move the discussion to [chat] ?

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed that you have < 20 CP. The main idea was not to create separate column which will copy the values of the generated ID but rather use the same column for two properties. If you would like to have separate column, I guess you would need to use @PrePersist callback lifecycle event and set it manually (although I'm not sure if at this stage you'll have the table generated value available)

Comment: I have done something like below: 1. open transaction 2. Save the object to DB 3. update the same object in DB to set the questid to questionorder 4. commit the transactioin. As shown in below code and it is working. Please suggest me, is there anything wrong/problem in this approach.                                
  tx = session.beginTransaction();
  hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(createQuestionnaire);
  qID = createQuestionnaire.getQuestionID();
  System.out.println("Question Category is :"+qID);
  updateQCategory(createQuestionnaire,qID);//updating the questorder in DB
  tx.commit();
 }

Comment: @chandu - sure, it's one of the ways to achieve what you want.